# Junit for Multiple static endpoint for SOAP based web service using boot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have multiple end point and static wsdl, my application is created using Spring boot, I am unable to find a way to write junit test cases for various end point.

```
1. SoapServerConfig
@EnableWs
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SoapServerConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext appContext){
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(appContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "beers")
    public SimpleWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema){
            SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        simpleWsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("beer.wsdl"));
        return simpleWsdl11Definition;
    }

 @Bean(name = "colddrink")
    public SimpleWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema){
            SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        simpleWsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("colddrink.wsdl"));
        return simpleWsdl11Definition;
    }



    @Bean
    public XsdSchema beersSchema(){
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/beers.xsd"));
    }
 @Bean
    public XsdSchema beersSchema(){
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/colddrink.xsd"));
    }

BeerEndpointIntegrationTest.java

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SoapServerConfig.class)
public class BeerEndpointIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;
    private Resource xsdSchema = new ClassPathResource("xsd/beers.xsd");

    @Before
    public void init(){
        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void valid_xsd_request_response_test() throws IOException {
        Source requestPayload = new StringSource(
                "<beer:getBeerRequest xmlns:beer=\"http://memorynotfound.com/beer\">" +
                        "<beer:id>1</beer:id>" +
                "</beer:getBeerRequest>");


        Source responsePayload = new StringSource(
                "<ns2:getBeerResponse xmlns:ns2=\"http://memorynotfound.com/beer\"></ns2:getBeerResponse>");

        mockClient
                .sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayload))
                .andExpect(noFault())
                .andExpect(payload(responsePayload))
                .andExpect(validPayload(xsdSchema));
    }

    @Test
    public void id_cannot_be_0_test() throws IOException {
        Source requestPayload = new StringSource(
                "<ns2:getBeerRequest xmlns:ns2=\"http://memorynotfound.com/beer\">" +
                        "<ns2:id>0</ns2:id>" +
                        "</ns2:getBeerRequest>");

        mockClient
                .sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayload))
                .andExpect(serverOrReceiverFault());
    }
}
```

In sample testcase I dint find a way to distinguish the declare url.

I have followed [Spring boot Spring ws security for soap based web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784617/spring-boot-spring-ws-security-for-soap-based-web-service) but there is only one url here we have multiple

Comment: can someone look in to it?